# Azure AD B2C - IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. (.Net 5 Web API + angular)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Angular app and a Web Api app (.Net 5.0) and I need a user to be authenticated with Azure AD B2C. So, when a user needs to reach some protected route he's going to be redirected to B2C log in page, authenticated and redirected back to the angular app. This Angular part works, no problem here.

Now, when the Angular app issues a request to a protected Web API (.Net 5), this web api should authorize the request. I've done this before in previous versions of .Net Core. But this is the new and shiny Microsoft Identity web. And it doesn't work.

## The set up

### appsettings.json for B2C

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "TenantId": "[Tenant Guid]",
    "Instance": "https://[tenant name].b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "[web api client Id]",
    "Domain": "[tenant name].onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signin"
  },
```

### startup.cs - ConfigureServices()

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
  {
    Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
  },
    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

// Creating policies that wraps the authorization requirements
services.AddAuthorization();

services.AddApplication();
services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);

services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
services.AddMemoryCache();

services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

### startup.cs - Configure()

```
...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  // endpoints.MapRazorPages();
  endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

With this set up all I get is **very** descriptive error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'System.String'.
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

But then I changed this "helper" sugar-configuration to the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; })
  .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
  {
    jwtOptions.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignInPolicyId"]}/v2.0/";
    jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
    jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
      OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
    };
});
```

And it works!

So is there a good docs on HOW MS Identity Web should be really configured? Why there is no precise description in the exception telling what is missing exactly?

## Update

Thanks for the answer but this Identity Web implementation is really poor.

The reason for this exception is either `SignUpSignInPolicyId` is undefined or misspelled! Microsoft team, you have to add it to your exception!

1. Add meaningful exceptions
2. If I don't want to use SignUpSignIn policy (I don't need any stranger go and register with my app), why it's not documented and supported?
3. Do use optional logging which would tell the developer what's wrong/missing!
4. use Builder pattern to create a configuration. Then it should be easier to identify which part of the config is missing in particular case.

Comment: The exception states that you can reach the OIDC metadata endpoint. That URL is constructed using the Authority, which is constructed using the instance, tenantId and policyId. For some reason it looks like the default config is not able to build/retrieve that URL.

Comment: This is the latest document to reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#initiate-the-authentication-libraries

Comment: 1) one example - this will not work, for a start services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

2) "exception states that you can reach the OIDC metadata endpoint" - REALLY? Where? show me this in the exception text.

3) Why can't this just tell me which part is missing?

Comment: I feel your pain with `Microsoft.Identity.Web`, the documentation and support is beyond poor, especially for .Net 5.0.

Comment: Also working on this and now .Net 6.0 is not improved. Same error. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change SignInPolicyId in app settings.json to SignUpSignInPolicyId

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application?tabs=visual-studio#add-the-app-settings

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C/TodoListService/appsettings.json

Comment: I do NOT need signupsignin policy - I do not want any user go and register with my app! I only need sign in policy.

Comment: That’s not the point, the key name is important. It’s used to build the OIDC metadata url, it doesn’t mean you need or will have sign up capability.

Comment: Why is there a need for a sign up/sign in policy in the first place?! this is the API, NOT THE CLIENT.

Comment: It’s because it forms part of the authority in AAD B2C, there HAS to be a policyId to construct the OIDC Metadata URL which hosts the token signing keys. SUSI is the most common, hence the key name.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT As in, this is a reference to the policy that was used to issue the token in the first place? So no authentication is actually carried out, this is purely for validation of the token itself?

Comment: Yes, thats all. The Key name is misleading, you just need a policyId so we can validate the tokens, because that is required to fetch the signing keys.

Answer (score 0):

Turns outs

```
 "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "",
    "Domain": "",
    "TenantId": "",
    "ClientId": "",
    "Authority": "",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

The Authority is missing. Really poor documentation indeed!